# Classpath to use for MapR/Hadoop/Hive

Tags: java, hadoop, mapr

I'm trying to compile some java code for hadoop and need to know what classpath I need to specify. For cloudera I use this below but what do I use for a MapR installation? Surprisingly I could only find how to set the classpath in google, not what to set it to.

```
javac -classpath "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-4.6.0-1.cdh4.6.0.p0.26/lib/hadoop/client/*" mr.java -d mr
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer by trial and error. Oddly google is very silent on this and all the books and examples I've read appear to assume this is too obvious to bother printing.

```
mkdir MyClass
javac -classpath "/opt/mapr/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.2/lib/*" MyClass.java -d MyClass
jar -cvf MyClass.jar -C MyClass .
```

Additionally, if you want the hive libraries, eg for compiling a hive UDF:

```
javac -classpath "/opt/mapr/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.2/lib/*:/opt/mapr/hive/hive-0.12/lib/*" MyClass.java -d MyClass
```

EDIT: one thing I would add is make sure you put quotes around the path, otherwise linux expands it on the command line which is not what you want. The * in the path needs to be passed to java as is.